# Limit UIPanGestureRecognizer when pinching using UIPinchGestureRecognizer, for iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I'm trying to create the typical pinch zoom and pan at the same time on an iPad view. The view itself contains 4 other subviews.
The issue I'm having is that while I can pinch zoom and pan at the same time, the panning goes way out of bounds to the point that you can move the view out of the frame.

I've tried several pan limitations, but they all seem to limit either the Y axis only, or both X and Y but only in the case of not being zoomed in.

Any suggestions?

Here's what I'm using for both pinch zoom and for pan gesture:

```
// for Pan Gesture
- (void) handlePanGestures:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
if (recognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded && recognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateFailed)
{
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint finalPoint = CGPointMake(recognizer.view.center.x + translation.x, recognizer.view.center.y + translation.y);

    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view.superview];
    recognizer.view.center = location;

    // set final position
    recognizer.view.center = finalPoint;
    [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self.view];
}
}

// for Pinch Gesture
- (void)handlePinches:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{

if([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
{
    // Reset the last scale, necessary if there are multiple objects with different scales
    self.currentScale = [gestureRecognizer scale];
}

if ([gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan ||
    [gestureRecognizer state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged)
{

    CGFloat currentScale = [[[gestureRecognizer view].layer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.scale"] floatValue];

    // Constants to adjust the max/min values of zoom
    const CGFloat kMaxScale = 2.0;
    const CGFloat kMinScale = 1.0;

    CGFloat newScale = 1 -  (self.currentScale - [gestureRecognizer scale]);
    newScale = MIN(newScale, kMaxScale / currentScale);
    newScale = MAX(newScale, kMinScale / currentScale);
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformScale([[gestureRecognizer view] transform], newScale, newScale);
    [gestureRecognizer view].transform = transform;

    self.currentScale = [gestureRecognizer scale];  // Store the previous scale factor for the next pinch gesture call
}
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, works for me!

```
-(void)moveViewWithGestureRecognizer:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer{

CGRect xRectRef = self.imageView.superview.frame;
CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.imageView];

CGPoint xyNew = CGPointMake(self.imageView.frame.origin.x + translation.x, self.imageView.frame.origin.y + translation.y);

if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged ) {

    if ( (xyNew.y <= xRectRef.origin.y) &&
        (xyNew.y + self.imageView.frame.size.height >= xRectRef.origin.y + xRectRef.size.height) &&
        (xyNew.x <= xRectRef.origin.x ) &&
        (xyNew.x + self.imageView.frame.size.width >= xRectRef.size.width+xRectRef.origin.x)){
        self.imageView.center = CGPointMake(self.imageView.center.x + translation.x,
                                             self.imageView.center.y + translation.y);
        [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointMake(0, 0) inView:self.imageView];
    }
}
```

}